# Как подключиться к MySQL на Zend Framework 2 через драйвер библиотеки PDO?

Tags: zend-framework-2, php_pdo

Установил ZF2 Skeleton Application, в файле global.php пишу следующее:

```
<? php
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=pass;host=localhost',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'
    ),
    'username' => 'name',
    'password' => 'pass',
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
),
);
?>
```

В php.ini раскомментировал:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

на сайте при запросе модуля, работающего с БД, пусто. =(

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

Теперь выдаёт ошибку:

> файл:/home/c/cmail1x6w/cmail1x6w.bget.ru/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php:331 сообщение: Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить localhost на 127.0.0.1

```
<? php
    return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=pass;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'
    ),
    'username' => 'name',
    'password' => 'pass',
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

Comment: Во-первых, вопрос был задан год назад. Во-вторых, ошибка в аутентификации пользователя, т.е. username или password неверны.